# Foundation 5 - change default font size without impacting grid

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, font-size

I'm working on a project using Zurb Foundation and need to change the base font-size from the default 16px to 13px without impacting the grid.

I attempted to do so by following the instructions in Foundation's settings as follows:

`$base-font-size: 13px;
 $rem-base: $base-font-size;`

However, this seems to have no impact on the size the font is rendered at. Am I simply missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Post here the content of your main.scss file (or similar if you have one with a different name). How do you compile SASS?

Comment: doesnt look like you have missed anything

Answer (score 1):

This should work as the variables are correctly used, you may be overriding the font size in the css. I have tested the code and it changes the font-size and does not affect the grid.